# modify JSON File

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Mvc4.Net project I am store my customer email in JSON file 
the format for that file like this

```
 {
  "p1":{
    "email":"xxx@hotmail.com"
  },
  "p3":{
    "email":"yyy@hotmail.com"
  }
 }
```

I surf the net searching what is the most easy way to modify this file (add new email).
I found a 100000 solution but I couldn't decide what is the most sample and easy way to do that.

My project is MVC .Net 4.5

Comment: So you want us to choose which one is the easiest *for you*?

Comment: I want the better way :)

Comment: Parse from JSON, add to the list, serialize (aka "stringy") back to JSON.  Reading the whole thing in, then writing the whole thing back out may seem weird, but this is the best way to use JSON

Comment: @Ali Nirabi: better than *what*? Anything that works is better than *nothing*.